Possible Error in Poizat's A Course in Model Theory (Chapter 7, Arithmetic)
I was reading Chapter 7 on Arithmetic in Bruno Poizat's A Course in Model Theory and noticed a potential error in Section 7.1 regarding the axioms defining the successor function.
The axiom is given as:
($\forall x) (x \neq 0)$
This seems incorrect since it should express that 0 is not the successor of any element. I believe the axiom should instead be:
($\forall x) (s(x) \neq 0)$
This revised version would mean that 0 cannot be the successor of any number, which is consistent with the usual properties of natural numbers under the successor function.
If the original version were correct, it would imply that every element is not equal to 0, which is clearly problematic in defining the natural numbers, as 0 itself must be included in the set.
Am I correct in interpreting this as an error in the text, or is there some subtlety I might be missing here? Any insight from those familiar with this text or similar material would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help and thoughts!

Yes, this is an error.

As Favier's comment says, yes, there is an (print) error. It should read as you have said:
$$\forall x\neg(sx=0)$$
Thus, we witness another instance for the importance of maintaining a book webpage listing the errata. In  complicated cases, such errors cause awful problems.
Let us, then, take the occasion to present a relevant, interesting discussion from Formal Logic: Its Scope and Limits (4th edition) by Richard Jeffrey:


This is not an answer to the question.

I've added a clarification.
